# Problem with connection to Neo4j test container using Spring boot 2 and JUnit5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, junit5

Problem with connection to Neo4j test container using Spring boot 2 and JUnit5
int test context. Container started successfully but spring.data.neo4j.uri property has a wrong default port:7687, I guess this URI must be the same when I call `neo4jContainer.getBoltUrl().`

Everything works fine in this case:

```
@Testcontainers
public class ExampleTest {

    @Container
    private static Neo4jContainer neo4jContainer = new Neo4jContainer()
        .withAdminPassword(null); // Disable password

    @Test
    void testSomethingUsingBolt() {

        // Retrieve the Bolt URL from the container
        String boltUrl = neo4jContainer.getBoltUrl();
        try (
            Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(boltUrl, AuthTokens.none());
            Session session = driver.session()
        ) {
            long one = session.run("RETURN 1", 
             Collections.emptyMap()).next().get(0).asLong();
            assertThat(one, is(1L));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But **SessionFactory** is not created for the application using autoconfiguration following to these recommendations - https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/neo4j/

When I try to create own primary bean - **SessionFactory** in test context I get the message like this - "URI cannot be returned before the container is not loaded"

But Application runs and works perfect using autoconfiguration and neo4j started in a container, the same cannot be told about the test context

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely 100% on Spring Boot's auto configuration (for production) in this case because it will read the `application.properties` or use the default values for the connection.

To achieve what you want to, the key part is to create a custom (Neo4j-OGM) `Configuration` bean. The `@DataNeo4jTest` annotation is provided by the `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure` module.

```
@Testcontainers
@DataNeo4jTest
public class TestClass {
  @TestConfiguration
  static class Config {
    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
          return new Configuration.Builder()
              .uri(databaseServer.getBoltUrl())
              .credentials("neo4j", databaseServer.getAdminPassword())
              .build();
    }
  }
 // your tests
}
```

For a broader explanation have a look at this [blog post](https://medium.com/neo4j/testing-your-neo4j-based-java-application-34bef487cc3c). Esp. the section *Using with Neo4j-OGM and SDN*.